NCryptOpenStorageProvider + KeyIso
Restarting the service after opening the provider breaks the connection and forces you to restart the entire application.
Step by step:

Open the provider NCryptOpenStorageProvider(myProvider, MS_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER, 0) — will be "00000000" (ERROR_SUCCESS)

Restart the CNG Key Isolation service

Reopen the provider NCryptOpenStorageProvider(myProvider, MS_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER, 0) — will be "80070006" (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE)


How to properly reopen the provider after restarting the service without restarting the application?

The ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE error is about the underlying invalid RPC binding handle between NCrypt (BCrypt) and the service. I don't think there's a documented way to reset that RPC binding handle, it's statically cached by the dll in your process memory, it might well also be by-design to avoid some security issues.

I understand that. What I don't understand is how the rest of the software survives the restart of this service and does not require a subsequent restart? How can I teach my application not to die too, but to automatically reconnect to the provider after the service was restarted?

really, when NCryptOpenStorageProvider with MS_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER called first time, MsProvCryptOpenProvider_KeyIso called from ncryptprov.dll and inside this function KeyIsoServerBind called. on next calls MsProvCryptOpenProvider_KeyIso also called, but KeyIsoServerBind called only once on first time and this is cache handle. for uncache need KeyIsoServerUnbind but from my fast look it called only from MSProvModuleUninit < UninitializeCNGProv which called on ncryptprov.dll unloaded. and look like no way unload this dll after it loaded as provider.

and not only your app if affected. system services too. after i restart keyiso service, i can not more unlock/login to windows with PIN. i got error something went wrong your pin isn't available ( code 0x80070006..)

when you first call
NCryptOpenStorageProvider(&hProvider, MS_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER, 0);
the ncryptprov.dll is loaded and when it function MsProvCryptOpenProvider_KeyIso called ( it is NCryptOpenStorageProviderFn from NCRYPT_KEY_STORAGE_FUNCTION_TABLE ) first time (the MsProvCryptOpenProvider_KeyIso called every time when you open MS_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER ) it call KeyIsoServerBind and cache some handle to KeyIso service. which of course became invalid after service restart. how i view, the KeyIsoServerUnbind (internal function in ncryptprov.dll) called only when ncryptprov.dll is unloaded. and ncrypt byself never unload already loaded providers, even after all handles to it was closed ( via NCryptFreeObject). so really no way fix this without process restart.
however i note that some windows buil-in components also affected. when i lock workstation and then try unlock it back, by using PIN provider, i got next error


Thanks a lot  I can't believe... I (you, we, they) can write a simple utility that will just restart this service once a minute — and force users around the world to constantly reboot their systems? Nice

@kazuser possible write and utility, which will be crash system. and so what ? sense ? in case LogonUI PIN logon - ngccredprovider do call to NgcSvc service (display name "Microsoft Passport"). and this service do another remote call, to NgcCtnrSvc ( "Microsoft Passport Container") and here already ncryptprov.dll do 3-rd remote call to KeyIso service ( "CNG Key Isolation" ) which fail do cached handle. however after restart NgcCtnrSvc PIN logon again work ok
